# fabric restarting my supervisord service kills the service

Tags: python, fabric, supervisord

I have a tornado web application running using supervisord. I manually start, stop and restart the Supervisord service from ssh and it works fine. I am using fabric from my local machine to do the following:

1. Run unit tests
2. commit/push to my git server
3. pull changes from development server
4. restart the Supervisord service to update the application

I get no errors when running the fabfile, but my server is down after I run it. The following is my fabfile code:

```
from fabric.api import *
from fabric.context_managers import settings

def prepare_deploy():
    local('py.test')
    local('git add .')
    x = raw_input('what would you like your commit message to be?   ')
    local('git diff --quiet --exit-code --cached || git commit -m "' + x + '"')
    local('git push origin master')

def dev():
    prepare_deploy()
    x = raw_input('Please enter the location of your keyFile for the dev server ')
    if x == '':
        key = 'key_file'
    else:
        key = x
    with settings(
            host_string='dev_server_name',
            user='user_name',
            Key_filename=key,
            use_ssh_config = True):
        code_dir='~/path/to/code/'
        with cd(code_dir):
            run("git pull origin master")
            run("sudo python setup.py install")
            run("sudo service supervisord restart")
```

After this is done, my web application is down. Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: What is in supervisor logs?

Comment: why do you restart the supervisord and not just the web application?

Comment: @ThomasFenzl I'm new to the way Supervisord works. How would I go about just restarting the application if Supervisord is the one who started it?

Comment: @twil I'm a Supervisord noob and my logs are empty of course.

Comment: use the command line tool [supervisorctl](http://supervisord.org/running.html#running-supervisorctl) to restart services: `sudo supervisorctl restart <service name>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Supervisor is a tool to manage services, there is no need to restart it just to restart something under its control.

It comes with a command line tool to manage processes, [supervisorctl](http://supervisord.org/running.html#running-supervisorctl). You can use it as a CLI interface or an interactive shell.

If you want to restart a service `supervisorctl restart <service name>` (with appropriate rights, so probably using `sudo` does that. If you changed the service's configuration, use `supervisorctl update` to restart affected processes. This way you get to use the logfile from supervisor in case your process doesn't start.

Comment: When I run `sudo supervisorctl restart Platform` I get the following error: `Platform: ERROR (abnormal termination)`

Comment: `Platform` being the name of my application

Comment: check the logfiles, usually in `/var/log/supervisor/`. There is a `supervisord.log` and two `Platform-std...` files with standard out and standard error.

Comment: okay thanks I'm the dumbest dude around. I had application errors. But your answer did help me with the `supervisorctl` interface. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Supervisor has bug in init.d script. Don't do `restart`. Do `stop` and then `start`.

Comment: No dice... The restart function works fine when I'm manually logged into the machine, as does starting and stopping, but neither works from my fabric file.